# Choose output depending on group

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings which differ only in one word.(E.g. `foo byte bar` and `foo word bar`). I used mutiple regex  to parse them.(E.g. `(\w+) byte (\w+)` -> `$1 1 $2` and `(\w+) word (\w+)` -> `$1 2 $2`) Is it possible to choose the output depending on the input word? (E.g. `(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)` -> `$1 <depending on $2> $3`) Tell me, if you need more examples.

Comment: You haven't said, but I assume you're using `replaceAll`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is best solved using `Matcher.appendReplacement` / `Matcher.appendTail` as follows:

```
String input = "hello byte world";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {

    // Compute replacement for middle word
    String w = m.group(2);
    String s = w.equals("byte") ? "<A BYTE!>"
             : w.equals("word") ? "<A WORD!>"
             : "something else";

    m.appendReplacement(sb, "$1 " + s + " $3");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

**Output:**

```
hello <A BYTE!> world
```

Comment: is it possible to use this `w.equals(...) ? ... : ...` in a regex?

Comment: @kaetzacoatl: You're confusing `replaceAll` with regular expressions. `replaceAll` is a method that *uses* regular expressions to find matches, but then does non-regex things (like produce the resulting string). I don't think `replaceAll` has the feature you want. What aioobe has done above is very generously do pretty much all the work for you to replace your current `replaceAll` code.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl, no, you can't let the replacement be a function of the match when using replaceAll. You have `$1`, `$2`, ... to work with. There's no way to express functions of them.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl, did my post (and last comment) answer your questions? Anything I should clarify?